# How to disable all tinyMCE textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a form with about 10 small tinyMCE editors, when I click the disable button, I want these fields to be readonly? Is this possible, non of then have id's. Can I do this via any method, may it be JavaScript, JQuery?

I tried these methods, but the do not work

```
tinyMCE.init( {mode: "none",readonly : true });
$('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: It is not a text input element. Its an iframe with content editable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will cycle over all of the editor instances and shut them down

```
for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, tinymce.editors[i].id);
}
```

Comment: The loop should not start removing from the head of the array. Each time an editor is removed, the length will decrease, and there will be a cross between the length and counter that will cause the loop to end earlier than desired, leaving editors left in the array. Removal should start from the tail. `for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, tinymce.editors[i].id);
}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are trying

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=436